# Spring Boot in-memory security with users from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot

I have a basic Spring Boot application which uses inMemoryAuthentication and a list of authorized users declared in the code:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("guest").password("{noop}guest1234").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
```

I'd like to move the user/roles list into the application.properties file, for example for the admin user:

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=password
spring.security.user.roles=ADMIN
```

However that does not seem to work as I'm getting a 403 error. What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Spring doesn't support this as far as I know. The only way to make a user admin is changing their role to admin. usually, if a backend DB is there then update the role column and map appropriate granted authorities accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spring security has only one default user ,
you can provide others by using your custom properties

```
...
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties properties;
...
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> builder = auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
        properties.getUsers().forEach(user -> {
            builder.withUser(user.getUsername()).password(user.getPassword()).roles((String[]) user.getRoles().toArray());
        });
    }
```

with your ApplicationProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private final List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public static class Users {
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private List<String> roles;
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public List<String> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }
    }

    public List<Users> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

and your .yaml file (yaml is less verbose than .properties files)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MyApp
...
application:
  users:
    -
      username: guest
      password: guest1234
      roles: USER
    -
      username: admin
      password: password
      roles: USER,ADMIN
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

For new Spring Boot 3.1.x (Spring security 6.1.x) it looks like:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
    User.UserBuilder builder = User.builder();
    List<UserDetails> users = appProps.getUsers().stream()
            .map(client -> builder.username(client.getName())
                    .password(client.getPassword())
                    .roles(client.getRole().name()).build())
           .toList();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
}

@ConfigurationProperties("app")
@Validated
@Getter
@Setter
public class AppProps {
...

  /*
    App users for Admin/Partner API
   */
  @NonNull
  private List<User> users;

  public record User(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String password, @NonNull List<Role> roles) {
  }
}
```

Credentials stored in `application_prod.yaml` (it's possible to secure password with `{bcrypt}`)

```
app:
   rest-clients:
   - name: admin
     password: "{noop}admin"
     role: ADMIN
   - name: partner
     password: "{noop}partner"
     role: PARTNER
```